# Give one word for the following phrase

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Is there one word for the following phrase?

To come to a conclusion without taking into consideration other parameters/ conditions ( jumping to a conclusion without ' definite and true ' knowledge about certain conditions ).

Comment: [**guess**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/guess) i guess

Answer (score 2):

Rash = Acting or done without careful consideration of the possible consequences; impetuous: 'it would be extremely rash to make such an assumption', 'a rash decision'

Impulsive = Acting or done without forethought: 'they’d married as impulsive teenagers', 'he regretted his impulsive offer'

Comment: Rash and impulsive fit more with describing general behaviour or an action. Doesn't seem to fit as well with this more scholarly task of reaching conclusions.

Comment: That's probably true. Jumping to conclusions is very much like taking rash decisions without considering all available info, isn't it so?

Answer (score 1):

*Conjecture* : used often in mathematics and law